# Names not being updated to a table?

Tags: python, sqlite

Here the table transform1 is being created and but the values of company are not being copied in the names of transform1. . .

```
for bad_char in special_chars:  
            company =  company.replace(bad_char, '')  
            cur.execute('Create table transform1 (Names Varchar, Transformtype Varchar')  
            cur.execute('Insert into transform1 (Names)', company)
```

Is there anything to do with the program !!! It shows me no errors

Comment: Show us your *actual* code as well as any exceptions you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit: `conn.commit()` or whatever your connection object is called.

Also, your identation must be broken. With that code, it will insert the company in the table for every bad_char that is in the list. And that can't be what you want to do?

And the sql statements are'nt correct as aix said...
The insert statement should be:  `cur.execute('Insert into transform1 (Names) values (?)', [company])` 
I did'nt test this code so I hope i did'nt missed something.

Here is a working sample of what I suppose you wanted to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/example')
cur = conn.cursor()

companies = ['Theninthö ä ABå', 'Some åther company']

# Create table
cur.execute('Create table transform1 (Names varchar(255), Transformtype varchar(255))')

for company in companies:
    # Fix bad characters
    special_chars = ['å', 'ä', 'ö']
    for bad_char in special_chars:
        company =  company.replace(bad_char, '')

    # Add company
    cur.execute('Insert into transform1 (Names) values (?)', [company])
    conn.commit()

# Show data
cur.execute('Select * from transform1')
data = cur.fetchall()

print data
```

Comment: To be honest, with SQL syntax like this I think that commits are the least of his worries.

Comment: Or, if you use windows, you have to put your db-file somewhere else of course.